# Magento - loading external php scripts inside controller

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Any time I want to load an external library from inside a class conforming to the Magento module approach. I am always faced with the following error:

> require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://example.com/HTML2PDF/tcpdf.php'

Despite that the URL is correct. For example:

```
class Foo_Bar_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController 
{
    public function whatever() {
        require_once(Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'HTML2PDF/tcpdf.php');
    }
}
```

Can anyone help understand why I cannot include files this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Mage::getBaseUrl()` function is for URLs, not file paths. So, it will return a string starting with "http://". What you want is `Mage::getBaseDir('lib')`.

The solution you provided works, but typically (and arguably) you should be putting third-party / external PHP scripts in the top-level `lib` folder. That way all third-party libraries are in one place and you don't have to even call `Mage::getModuleDir()`. Your folder structure would be:

```
/magento/
  app/
    code/
      local/
        Foo/
          Bar/
            controllers/
              AccountController.php
  ...
  lib/
    HTML2PDF/
      tcpdf.php
```

And your controller would be:

```
<?php
    class Foo_Bar_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController 
    {
        public function whatever() {
            require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . DS . 'HTML2PDF/tcpdf.php');
        }
    }
```

What's even better is that when you have files in the base `lib`, they are included in the autoloader's search for classes. So sometimes you can get away with simply instantiating the class, and the autoloader does the work of finding the correct file to require.

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have figured it out. Not sure why, but I believe Magento somehow doesn't allow including files outside your own module. Anyways this seems to work:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('', 'Foo_Bar'). DS . 'lib' . DS . 'tcpdf_6_2_11' . DS . 'tcpdf.php';
```

Just by adding a custom folder inside my module and then calling Magento's **Mage::getModuleDir** method it works!

If anyone can better explain why this happens then it may help others (myself included) understand better.

Thanks